# DisplayPort won't wake up screen when laptop placed in docking station

Tags: arch-linux, kde, displayport

My laptop is connected to an external monitor via DisplayPort(in a port in the docking station). When I boot my laptop while it is connected to the docking station everything works fine, but if I detach the laptop from the docking station and reattach it, the external monitor does not wake up. It does recognize something happened, as it display a power-saving mode message, but, but it remains black. The laptop itself thinks it's connected, as it switches to the multi-monitor mode.

I'm running Arch Linux on a Dell Latitude E7440 with kernel version `3.16.1-1-ARCH` and KDE 4.14.0. I have the `xf86-video-intel` driver installed. I'm using `kscreen`for monitor management, but even if I go to the system settings to set it up manually I can't wake up the screen.

When I connected the same screen via DVI it worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to install [Laptop Mode Tools](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/laptop-mode-tools).

Comment: Thanks for the tipp. It also solved the problem that from time to time one of the external monitors wouldn't wake up properly after energy saving mode. With laptop-mode-tools, I now can plug the laptop out of the docking station and back in to fix it.

Comment: BTW - I can't confirm it, but I believe Laptop Mode Tools also help regulation the cooling mechanism, preventing overheating.